# Boot order breaking due to automount (running into emergency mode)

Tags: raspbian-buster, mount, filesystem, sudo, fstab

I have a Raspberry Pi running *Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)*.
The Pi is running on a microSD-Card with a *read-only* boot partition and activated *overlay-filesystem* (both is currently *deactivated* for testing).

The `fake-hwclock.data` (current system time) is written to (and read from) a mounted USB, so that when the machine reboots, it starts on the "current" time (last time before reboot) and not the time from before the *overlay filesystem* has been enabled.

To make sure that important logs are also saved, these are written to the USB too.

The USB is mounted with the following line (`/etc/fstab`):

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/storage ext4 defaults,user,noatime 0 0
```

All of this is (or was) working fine. But since i removed the **sudoer** privileges from the *pi* user aswell as set a password for the *root* user, the RasPi starts (about every 2nd time) in **emergency mode** - even though, the *pi* user should have the privileges to mount the USB (see `"user"` in `/etc/fstab`).

In emergency mode I'm able to print the journal logs, using `journalctl -xb`:

```
mnt-storage.mount: Found ordering cycle on local-fs-pre.target/start
mnt-storage.mount: Found dependency on systemd-remount-fs.service/start
mnt-storage.mount: Found dependency on systemd-fsck-root.service/start
mnt-storage.mount: Found dependency on fake-hwclock.service/start
mnt-storage.mount: Found dependency on mnt-storage.mount/start
mnt-storage.mount: Job local-fs-pre.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with mnt-storage.mount/start
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping Local File Systems (Pre)
```

When reading this, I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong) that `local-fs-pre.target` has a dependency on `fake-hwclock.service` which in turn has a dependency on `mnt-storage.mount` - which then breaks the boot cycle.

- Does the *pi* user **need** *sudoer* rights to mount the USB on startup?
- Shouldn't the `"user"` param in `/etc/fstab` solve that problem?
- Could the *root* user be causing problems because I set its password? (???)

Comment: It is difficult to see what you are trying to do. Nothing writes to the boot partition (except firmware updates) it doesn't even NEED to be mounted! After 10 years with 8 (or more) Pi  most running 24/7I have only had 2 SD Cards wear out.

Comment: This isn't the boot partition, this is the USB stick which is (or should be) mounted on `/mnt/storage` --> `mnt-storage.mount`. I am not really familiar with systemd, so please tell me if I'm off the track here.

Comment: This still makes no sense. If you don't have a user with root privileges the system would be unusable. If you want to write system/log files to storage it NEEDS to mounted by root before boot.

Comment: I don't get it. I do have a *root* user - which still is a *sudoer*. I only removed the *pi* user from *sudoers*.

Comment: About the first comment; I don't have any experience with Pi, i just read some articles (e.g. [this one from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/8r54f0/how_fast_will_a_sd_card_wear_out/)) about the lifespan being short if it has a lot of write operations.

Comment: *"Does the pi user need sudoer rights to mount the USB on startup?"* -> Not if you have  `user` in fstab.  However, that doesn't mean it *will* be automounted by some user other than root (which one?).   Hence the point is a bit moot -- ie., your problem has nothing to do with whether or not the pi user can mount a partition at boot because based on the information in your question, there's no attempt to have it mounted that way.  It's listed in fstab and does not have `noauto`, so it will be automounted at boot the same way everything else is.

Comment: *"I don't have any experience with Pi, i just read some article"* -> By analogy, if you had never ridden in a car before and read a bunch of articles about car crashes online, you might decide never to try such a crazy thing.  **Unless you have a real reason to do this, don't bother.**  I'm not promising you won't have one later (there are some use cases where it might be justified), but the great majority of pi users, including all of the top users here, have not had to do this as far  as I am aware, and we've been using Pis for the better part of a decade.

Comment: @goldilocks Ohh.. so `user` would only be of use if I want to mount it during runtime? // The problem is - it is not getting mounted the same way *everything else* is. It's not getting mounted at all and this has never happened before. The only thing I've changed was I removed sudoer rights from *pi* and gave *root* as password.

Comment: That's purely coincidental, then.  The problem is the dependency loop -- why that wasn't a problem before I can't say.  That emergency mode doesn't occur *every time* implies there is something non-deterministic, although the dependency loop should be (the same every time).  Sorry I can't help further, other than to say again that this (using overlayfs) is probably a bad way to start off with the Pi, which tends to include a bit of a learning curve for most people anyway, I think.

Comment: Damn, alright. I was really sure, that tI *$!@# up my user permissions. Thanks anyways for the information (and pointing the problem out again)! - I was having tunnel vision. Oh and btw i disabled the overlayfs. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your Question addresses 2 issues- SD Card reliability and pi user permissions and seems to conflate them.

It has long been recognised that having a default username/password is a security risk.
Changing password is simple and encouraged, but changing user pi is NOT.

User 0 on Raspberry Pi OS is "special" and built into many of the programs.

The recent [Update to Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/) removes the default “pi” user  and creates a user the first time you boot a newly-flashed Raspberry Pi OS image.

For existing systems update adds a mechanism to change the name of user 0 `sudo rename-user`. This is also available on updated Buster installations. This may require pi to have sudo privileges.

Rather than changing user 0 or adding a root login it is better to change default username and add additional accounts with restricted privileges.

Comment: Sorry, but 1. where did I ask anything about SD card reliability? I simply made a statement about my setup. 2. It seems I had (or still have) a very flawed understanding of the Linux user permissions. But I don't see, where your answer actually *answers* my question(s)? It's not that I don't think that information is useful - it is, thank you! - but I think adding an explanation as to why my assumptions about the user permissions were wrong, would've been far more helpful (as well as answering my actual question).

Comment: @eDonkey your question was based on trying to avoid writing to SD Card - which goldilicks addressed.  I admit this was an assumption on my part, but you did not explain how this is different to the hundreds of similar questions. The answer above is meant as a helpful guide to normal practice for someone who  stated "I don't have any experience with Pi, i just read some article"